# UTF-8 encoding in Volley Requests

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, android-volley

In my Android app I am loading json data with a Volley `JsonArrayRequest`. The data were created by myself and I saved them with Sublime with UTF-8 encoding. When I get the `Response` and fill my `ListView`, the texts are not displayed correctly (umlauts). This is what my Request looks like:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(targetUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            fillList(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

When I load the exact same data with this method, all texts are displayed correctly:

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(request);
        try {
            final HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            final StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                final InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So to me it seems like there is no problem with the encoding of my json file. How can I fix this encoding problem in Volley?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have used UTF-8 encoded JSON files and it has worked correctly. Are you setting the "Content-Type" header when you serve the file? Volley should read that and build it's response appropriately.

Comment: No, I don't set this header. I didn't know that I have to do that. DoO you have an example for me?

Comment: Are you serving the JSON files on a server? Wherever you are processing the request for those files, you want to specify a return header with something like "Content-Type text/json charset=utf-8".

Comment: I just uploaded the JSON files on my private webspace via FTP.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you know that absolutely all of the files you are requesting will be in the UTF-8 format, which it sounds like you do, then you might consider forcing your Volley request to return UTF-8 formatted strings. You could accomplish this by subclassing the standard JSON request. Something like this:

```
public class Utf8JsonRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8String), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log error
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // log error
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see now that you are using a `JsonArrayRequest`. You could subclass that instead. I don't have the syntax handy, but it would be pretty similar.

Comment: It works. And overriding parseNetworkResponse in my StringRequest also solved the problems I had with some XML Feeds I was loading. Thanks @xaevinx

Comment: Hey @JensJensen , how did this fix your problem? I tried extending both `JsonArrayRequest` and `JsonRequest<JSONArray>` and none worked. I still get "?????" as the response. When I go to the `php` service in Chrome `json` is displayed properly, however when debugging, when reading the received json it appears to be ???? so it should be `Volley`'s fault again. It's strange that we have to override `Volley`'s encoding as in JsonRequest class, it's using UTF8 - `protected static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";`

Comment: why `HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers)` isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 16):

I have same problem like this and i solve it using UTF-8 charset.

```
String str = "";
try {
     str = new String(strFromService.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
}

String decodedStr = Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
```

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 10):

donot use try{} catch  in the   onResponse block, that is giving some problem in my code , rather than that  you can  implement like this .

```
@Override 
onResponse(String s) {

s= fixEncoding(s);
Toast.makeToast(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

and i think you will get the required result

```
 public static String fixEncoding(String response) {
            try {
                byte[] u = response.toString().getBytes(
                        "ISO-8859-1");
                response = new String(u, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

This is worked as a charm for me,, I just created a static method from @Muhammad Naeem's answer,, Thanks Muhammed..

```
public static String fixEncodingUnicode(String response) {
    String str = "";
    try {
        str = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String decodedStr = Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
    return  decodedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

another approach: you can encode your whole response by this line of code.

```
newStr = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(oldStr, "iso8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

I have encoded whole response string into UTF-8 as I know volley default encode method is iso8859-1

Answer (score 4):

Add this line of code inside response of volley :

```
 public void onResponse(String response) 
    {

     if (response != null) 
      {
        response=new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify in server part set utf-8 in content type like  "text/html;charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier two days ago and i have tried every thing my friends just said and it`s the same problem and i tried so meany things .. 
my file is written in php and using volley to get the data as json i followed these steps to solve the problem ..

1. before executing the query in your database write this query

   mysqli_query($this->connection,"set_NAMES_utf8");
2. use this header in your file if it`s php

   header('Content-Type: application/json ; charset=utf-8 ');
3. while you are echoing the json according to php there is a solve for this problem 
   use this special charachter in `json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

   i hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I just use this code line in my **public void onResponse(){}** method and It's work pretty well.

```
          if (response != null){
                try {
                    response=new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    response=new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    parseArray(jsonArray);

                } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```