# Charset encoding issue from parsed html text

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having some charset encoding/decoding problem.

What I'm doing is:

1. I'm implementing UrlPreivewLoader class like facebook.
2. I'm using volley stringrequest to get a html document from web.
3. I'm parsing metaTags for title, imageurl, description(eg. og:title)
4. I want to support all kinds of languages, any links.

The problem is, Title and description text of some links are not properly shown(cracked) in my android app.

I've already tried a few links' advice as follwing.
[UTF-8 encoding in Volley Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932123/utf-8-encoding-in-volley-requests/35172597)

```
public static String fixEncodingUnicode(String response) {
    String str = "";
    try {
        str = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String decodedStr = Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
    return  decodedStr;
}
```

It seems It works some English web pages, but didn't work in Non-English web pages such as charset is EUC-KR. So I've decided to know all combinations of encoding and decoding pairs as follows. And I've found some pairs that works properly.

**The Question is, How can I set danamically proper Encoding/Decoding pairs for all languages including Non-English alpabets?**

```
public static void checkEncodingCombination(String parsedHtmlTitle) {
    String str = "";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry : Charset.availableCharsets().entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry2 : Charset.availableCharsets().entrySet()) {
            try {
                str = new String(parsedHtmlTitle.getBytes(entry.getValue().toString()), entry2.getValue().toString());
                LOGS.d(TAG, "encodingCharset: " + entry.getValue().toString()
                        + ", decodingCharset: " + entry2.getValue().toString() + ", str: " + str);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: Please remove `new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")`. It's garbage: `new String("A—1".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8").equals("A?1")`

Comment: The problem is in your request and response. By the time the data gets to `response` it's a UTF-16 encoded Unicode string (like all Java strings) that is either corrupt or just fine. Please show your request and response HTTP headers.