# Android Studio Weird error with volley and response from volley

Tags: android, android-studio

Am I missing something, I am trying to create a loginActivity and I created this code, and I have a log that logs the answer to the volley I created...But The if statement is not getting entered...Can someone see something I'm doing wrong? Sorry if its really dump( and yes I tried to change the response.equals check to be    response.equals(" Password Accepted!");, this did not work either) 
Another thing to note, yes I know my search in the log is different then the tag, it doesnt login, (which is what i want it to do)
[image]

```js
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.e("Before Conversion",response);

                String convertedResponse = null;

                try {
                    convertedResponse = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    L.e("After Conversion",convertedResponse);
                if (convertedResponse.equals("Password Accepted!")) {
                    showProgress(false);

                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    msg.obj = succcess ? 1 : 0;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

```
06-29 15:24:04.990 16707-16707/E/Before Conversion: Password Accepted!
```

06-29 15:24:04.990 16707-16707/E/After Conversion: Password Accepted!
After suggestion to change logging...
    06-29 15:34:32.339 16707-16707/ E/Got a response:: Password Accepted!

**UPDATE**
After creating a JSON array of length 1 with just the response string and a key for it, and passing it to my android studio code, the json array wont parse through the functions used to parse it (JSON Object, JSON Array), but manually parsing the response string works..... Less graceful then I would like it but i guess it works....
[image]

Comment: Try printing some Log inside if statement.

Comment: i already tried that it doesnt get printed, so it doesnt even enter the if statement

Comment: @jewstin hey! problem is not solved yet? Can you change your comparison this way: https://pastebin.com/tTySyaN8

Comment: Hey phen0menon I appreciate all your help, but it sitll does not work with either way

Comment: @phen0menon, this is a bit of a stupid idea, but what if I created a one element JSON array and parsed the json array for the first value, and used that?

Comment: @jewstin Well, you can check it out, but the best way is to change response of the server to a simplified value. Or, if you want, I can check this request by myself. We can continue discussion in Discord: `seeth3r#9808`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when encoding of response is not UTF-8. Try converting response like this:

```
String convertedResponse = null;

try {
    convertedResponse = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    // do your things ...
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It contains the exact same string both before I call the convertedresponse string and the response from teh server ill update it

Comment: see it has the same response for "Before Conversion" and :"After Conversion"

Comment: @jewstin can you please set logger like this: https://pastebin.com/3TMTaC2z

Comment: 06-29 15:34:32.339 16707-16707/com.fzhang.nhchecklistcaregiver E/Got a response:: Password Accepted!  (This shows up) but the login success doesnt

Comment: @jewstin I think this is not a volley error... Well, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932123/utf-8-encoding-in-volley-requests). But if you can change the response of the server, change it to, let's say, "1" or "0" and then try compare with these values.

Comment: I don't think I can change the server at all, that is out of my control....

Comment: @jewstin Well, I dont really see that this is a problem of request. Try check something like `System.out.println(convertedResponse == "Password Accepted!")` and `System.out.println(convertedResponse.equals("Password Accepted!")` and see what's happening.

Comment: funny both of those return false

Comment: @jewstin try again this: `System.out.println(convertedResponse.trim().equals("Password Accepted!"))`

Answer (score 0):

your response is in JSONObject not JSONArray, so on Response Listnere use:

```
if(response.getString("response").equals("PASSWORD ACCEPTED!"){
//do what you want to do
}
```