# Volley parameter with accent, sent as special character (�)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I want to make a volley post request to my server, but when sending a parameter with an accent, the accent turns into �. If I make a request through my web application or through postman, the accent is accepted on the server. The problem is when the parameter pass through volley.

Here is an example of my function to make a volley post request.

```
fun post(path: String, params: JSONObject, headers: HashMap<String, String>, completionHandler: (response: JSONObject?) -> Unit) {
    val jsonObjReq = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, basePath + path, params,
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                Log.d(TAG, "/post request OK! Response: $response")
                val key = "code"
                val value = 200
                response.put(key, value)
                completionHandler(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.d(TAG, "/post request fail! Error:" + error.message)
                completionHandler(null)
            }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json ; charset=utf-8")
            return headers
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 encoding in Volley Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932123/utf-8-encoding-in-volley-requests)

Comment: No, on that question the problem is receiving the data, my problem is when I send the data to the server :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when looking at the source-code of [Request.java](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Request.java), it prominently states:

```
/**
 * Default encoding for POST or PUT parameters.
 * See {@link #getParamsEncoding()}.
**/
private static final String DEFAULT_PARAMS_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
```

make sure that the source-code file (there usually is a small indicator bottom right in Android Studio) and the posted content do have `UTF-8` encoding (it's a quite common issue in web development, which might also apply here). in case the content does not have `UTF-8` encoding, it needs to be converted before posting it, in order not to end up with the `�` replacement character. see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47842656/549372) for the `String` conversion.

also check the encoding of the script, the database connection and the database on the server-side once; if any of these do not support `UTF-8`, it won't work. it's not neccessarily a client-side issue (which should support `UTF-8` out of the box).